# psql: FATAL: role "Stephen" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, osx-lion

I am trying to setup a toy database that I can create and destroy at will.  I don't want to use the `postgres` user in case I destroy something important.  I did the following:

```
$ psql -h localhost -U postgres
postgres=# \du
                       List of roles
 Role name |            Attributes             | Member of 
-----------+-----------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB | {}

postgres=# create user Stephen createdb;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# \du
                   List of roles
 Role name |            Attributes             | Member of 
-----------+-----------------------------------+-----------     
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB | {}
 stephen   | Create DB                         | {}

postgres=# ^D\q
```

Then when I try and connect, I get the following error:

```
$ psql -h localhost 
psql: FATAL:  role "Stephen" does not exist
$ psql -h localhost -U Stephen
psql: FATAL:  role "Stephen" does not exist
```

This makes no sense to me.  I can see the user, stephen, but it won't let me use it.  What am I missing?

I am using psql 9.0.10 on OS X Lion.

Comment: [You might want to consult the excellent manual on the matter.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to write it case-sensitive:

```
$ psql -h localhost -U stephen
```

As your role name starts with a small `s`?

Comment: Hmmm, that seems to be the case.  Why is it creating it with a small `s` when I explicitly use a large `S`?

Comment: If I do `create user "Stephen" createdb;` (interestingly, with double-quotes) then it creates a user with the proper case.  I accept your answer.

Comment: Sorry noticed your second question too late, glad you found the answer :)

Comment: @StephenRasku: Unquoted identifiers are folded to lower case, double quoted ones preserve their case.

Answer (score 1):

Logins are case-sensitive - "Stephen" is different from "stephen".